# Why are there two different folders for storing the same VirtualBox VM and how can I consolidate them to a single folder?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have the following folder:

/Users/MyUser/Documents/VMs

Underneath it are the folders / files:

> /Users/MyUser/Documents/VMs/WinDev1612Sys
>   /Users/MyUser/Documents/VMs/WinDev1612Sys/Logs
>   /Users/MyUser/Documents/VMs/WinDev1612Sys/Snapshots
>   /Users/MyUser/Documents/VMs/WinDev1612Sys/WinDev1612Sys.vbox
>   /Users/MyUser/Documents/VMs/WinDev1612Sys/WinDev1612Sys.vbox-prev

But all the files in that folder are very small (a few KB), and can't possibly by my Windows 10 VM.

But then underneath my user folder, is another folder I didn't create which has the following folders and files:

```
/Users/MyUser/VirtualBox VMs/   
/Users/MyUser/VirtualBox VMs/WinDev1612Sys   
/Users/MyUser/VirtualBox VMs/WinDev1612Sys/Windev1612Sys-disk1.vmdk
```

The last file is 45GB, and is surely my VM. 
So why are all my files spread across these two folders ? Parallels used to have everything in just one file (which you could look inside to see the contents), and it was easy to move.

Is there a way to consolidate all the files, so that all files for my VM (WinDev1612Sys) is under a single root folder (VMs)?

Comment: VirtualBox doesn't store VMs at 'Users/MyUser/Documents/VMs/' that's VMWare location

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have VMWare installed - when I was setting up my VM it asked the location and I specified that.

Comment: All it appears you selected is the new location for the data files and it used the default location for the configuration files

Comment: @Ramhound How do I integrate it into one folder ?